# Sqlite.Net PCL And Sqlite-Net Extensions

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

I'm trying to use this lib: 
https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL
so I can keep all my repository stuff in a PCL.

And https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/overview
Because is way better to manage the relationship between entities with it.

I have tried to build them using PCL profile 4.5 - 78, but no success so far. Especially in the Sqlite-Net Extension that use some heavy reflection that won't work/compile on PCL.

Does anyone made this two work together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last SQLite-Net Extensions version works with SQLite.Net-PCL out-of-the-box and the PCL library project is now compiled against [SQLite.Net-PCL NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL/). Default profile is Profile158 (.Net 4.5, SL5, WP8, Win8, Xam.Droid & Xam.Touch).

**EDIT:** The library is now available as [a NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLiteNetExtensions/). So it should be simpler to include it.